# Where to pass values from querystring to dropdownlists and refresh grid if !ispostback

Tags: webforms

There is a simple form that has 6 dropdownlists and a gridview. When any of the dropdownlists change the value filters the grid by altering the selectcommand. A user can navigate in another page through a row of the grid.

From the other page a user has a back button that loads the page WITH a querystring which has the values of the dropdownlists.

I want to accomplish 2 things:

1) To put the values in the dropdownlists. This i have done easily.

2) The next thing is to make the grid show data based on this values. this is its normal operation.

I thought that if i add the following code in page load would do the trick but it didnt. I tried all the events but no luck.I can get the dropdownlists to hold the value i want but the grid shows ALL records:

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ret"] != null)
        {
            string[] retvalues = Request.QueryString["ret"].Split('_');
            Update_Search(retvalues);
            dsTodo.SelectCommand = dsTodo.SelectCommand + Build_Where();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

The last 2 lines exist in the selectedvaluechange evnets on the dropdownlists and they work fine to filter the grid in normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `SelectCommand` but you are not executing it. Do this:

```
dsTodo.SelectCommand = dsTodo.SelectCommand + Build_Where();
dsTodo.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
GridView1.DataBind();
```

That's assuming that the `DataSourceID` property of the `GridView1` is set to `dsTodo`.

Comment: nothing changed....I found out that my problem may rest in another area...although i get the querystring values in an array it seems that i am having trouble in setting them in the dropdownlist.... i am using srProject.Items.FindByValue(retvalues[0].ToString()).Selected = true; to fill the dropdownlists now but i cant see them selected and are not passed through to the selectcommand....thanks anyway i think i may research more and open another question :(

Comment: @e4rthdog whatever the problem is, it's not sufficient to set the `SelectCommand` to the `SqlDataSource`, you need to execute it by calling the `Select` method and then bind the `GridView`. Good luck.